# Pass Item By Item To PayPal

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms

This is the syntax I am using, I have verified that my `Session` variables hold the proper value, but when the `paypal` page loads the only items that are shown is quantity and total.  Why am I not getting each individual item, item price and quantity displayed on the `paypal` page?

```
protected void ppal()
{
    redirecturl += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" 
    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ppl"].ToString()
    + "&first_name=" + Session["name"] 
    + "&city=" + Session["city"] 
    + "&state=" + Session["State"] + "&item_name_1=" + Session["item1"]
    + "&amount_1=" + Session["itemprice"] 
    + "&quantity_1=" + Session["qty1"] 
    + "&item_name_2=" + Session["item2"] 
    + "&amount_2=" + Session["itemprice2"]
    + "&quantity_2=" + Session["qty2"] 
    + "&amount=" + amount 
    + "&night_phone_a=" + Session["phone"] 
    + "&address1=" + Session["address"] 
    + "&business=abcdefgs@hotmail.com" 
    + "&shipping=0" + "&handling=0" 
    + "&tax=" + Session["tax"]
    + "&currency=" + Session["currency"]
    + "&return=" 
    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString() 
    + "&cancel_return=" 
    + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();
    Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple items are not supported with a "Buy Now" button, which is what you are specifying with `_xclick`. You would instead want to use `cmd=_cart` and then also include `upload=1`